# How to add limit on selecting list

Tags: jquery, html, css

Hi i'm new to jQuery and I want to allow people to select only 5 categories and on each selection & deletion, the number should be reduced & increased and instead of this "You can add up to 5 categories" it should show this "You can add 4 more categories."

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
 var one = $('.select-manage-category').val();
 var two = $('.select-manage-category1').val();
 var three = $('.select-manage-category2').val();
 $('.select-manage-category, .select-manage-category1, .select-manage-category2').change(function() {
  var one = $('.select-manage-category').val();
  var two = $('.select-manage-category1').val();
  var three = $('.select-manage-category2').val();
  if (one && two && three) {
   $("#add-category").prop("disabled", false).css({
    'font-weight': 'bold'
   });
  } else {
   $("#add-category").prop("disabled", true).css({
    'font-weight': 'normal'
   });
  }
 });
 $('#add-category').click(function() {
  $('#selected-lst-values').append('<option value="' + $(this).val() + '">' + $('.select-manage-category').val() + ' << ' + $('.select-manage-category1').val() + ' << ' + $('.select-manage-category2').val() + '</option>');
 });
  
 $('#selected-lst-values option').each(function() {
  if ($(this).val() == '') {
    alert('ffdgdfgf');
   $('#remove-category').prop('disabled', true).css({
    'font-weight': 'normal'
   });
  } else {
   $('#remove-category').prop('disabled', false).css({
    'font-weight': 'bold'
   });
  }
 });
  
   $('#remove-category').click(function() {
  $('#selected-lst-values option:selected').remove();
 });
});
```

```css
.select-manage-category,
.select-manage-category1,
.select-manage-category2 {
  width: 100px;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 4px;
}

p {
  clear: left;
  text-align: center;
}

#selected-lst-values {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div><select class="form-control select-manage-category" size="5">
    <option>Paper Manufacturers</option>
    <option>Paper Products Suppliers</option>
    <option>Paper Chemicals Suppliers</option>
</select></div>

<div><select class="form-control select-manage-category1" size="5">
    <option>Paper Converters</option>
    <option>Lab Apparatus & Supplies</option>
    <option>Service Providers</option>
  </select></div>
<div><select class="form-control select-manage-category2" size="5">
    <option>Molded Pulp Products</option>
    <option>Software Vendors</option>
    <option>Information Services</option>
  </select>
</div>
<p style="padding-top:10px;color:red;">You can add up to 5 categories</p>
</div>
<input id="add-category" name="add" type="button" value="Add Category" disabled="true">
<input id="remove-category" name="add" type="button" value="Remove Category" disabled="true">
<div><select id="selected-lst-values" class="form-group percent-100" size="7" multiple="multiple">
       </select></div>
<button id="mnage-category-savebtn" class="btn btn-md btn-radius pi-btn prodetails-btn" type="button"><strong>Save Categories</strong> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-right right-arrow-head-icon"></span></button>
```

Comment: you can count the numbers of children you have inside the category list - 5 and you got how many left...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a working version which will handle showing how many available select. Code is a bit messy due to falling sleep process...

```
<pre> <code> https://jsfiddle.net/at8ahu7c/2/ </code> </pre>
```

But just ask if you have a question, hope it help! Cheer!!

Comment: Thank you so much Tran:) But, I want to show this(You can add 4 more categories) message when the count decrease i.e On first, Message should be like this " You can add up to 5 categories " and When i add values, The message should be like this " You can add 4 more categories ". I tried some hide() & show() concept but its not working  for me.

Comment: Ah sorry my bad! You can change the text on <span id="target"> add up to 5 </span> and change the whole text when click button. Check how many available choices then replaces it with correct text. Don't need to use hide() and show() fucntion

Comment: Very sorry Tran. I didn't understand. Can you explain it through fiddle, Please?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/at8ahu7c/4/   Please check this. function setAvailableChoice() now will set some text not only number so edit that text based on what you need. :D